# The distances between the QPushButton in QGridLayout

Tags: python, user-interface, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

I wrote the following program which draws a minefield for game the sapper

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import mainw, sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class WindowSapper(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    buttons=[]

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self,parent)
        self.ui=mainw.Ui_mainwin()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        for i in xrange(10):
            l=[]
            for j in xrange(10):
                b=QtGui.QPushButton()
                l.append(b)
                self.ui.gridLayout.addWidget(b, i, j, 1, 1)
            self.buttons.append(l)

def main():
    app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window=WindowSapper()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I apply also the form module

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'mainw.ui'
#
# Created: Tue Nov 27 08:52:39 2012
#      by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.9.4
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    _fromUtf8 = lambda s: s

class Ui_mainwin(object):
    def setupUi(self, mainwin):
        mainwin.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("mainwin"))
        mainwin.resize(546, 530)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(mainwin)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.gridLayoutWidget = QtGui.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 30, 521, 461))
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("gridLayoutWidget"))
        self.gridLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.gridLayout.setMargin(0)
        self.gridLayout.setHorizontalSpacing(6)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("gridLayout"))
        mainwin.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(mainwin)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 546, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menubar"))
        mainwin.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(mainwin)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
        mainwin.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(mainwin)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(mainwin)

    def retranslateUi(self, mainwin):
        mainwin.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("mainwin", "Сапер", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))


class mainwin(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_mainwin):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, f=QtCore.Qt.WindowFlags()):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent, f)

        self.setupUi(self)
```

But it did not meet my expectations: the buttons are not completely filled GridLayout, among them there are free spaces, that is, they are not completely filled cell GridLayout. How to get rid of these gaps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first reason you are seeing a ton of spacing is actually not because of the `QGridLayout`, but because nothing is constraining your layout objects to make them bunch up together. What you would need to do is add a stretch to the layout to eat up as much space as possible, forcing the rest of the items to push together.

QGridLayout does allow you to add stretch items to it, but I think that makes the grid more complicated to navigate later because you always have to account for that spacer row/col. So instead you can just wrap the grid layout in a vertical/horizontal layout and add spacers to those.

Once you do this, you will notice a tiny amount of space left between the rows. Apparently this is just a known thing with QGridLayout ([see this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203669/remove-all-spacing-in-qgridlayout)). But you can play with the size of the buttons, and the min size of the row and columns to get it right:

Here is an example (standalone - not needing your UI module)

```
class WindowSapper(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self,parent)
        self.resize(450,350)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.vLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.hLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()

        self.gridLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout.setSpacing(0)

        # center the grid with stretch on both sides
        self.hLayout.addStretch(1)
        self.hLayout.addLayout(self.gridLayout)
        self.hLayout.addStretch(1)

        self.vLayout.addLayout(self.hLayout)
        # push grid to the top of the window
        self.vLayout.addStretch(1)

        self.buttons = []
        for i in xrange(10):
            l=[]
            for j in xrange(10):
                b=QtGui.QPushButton()
                b.setFixedSize(40,30)
                l.append(b)
                self.gridLayout.addWidget(b, i, j)
                self.gridLayout.setColumnMinimumWidth(j, 40)
            self.buttons.append(l)
            self.gridLayout.setRowMinimumHeight(i, 26)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you explain it to me why we use `l.append(b)` and `self.buttons.append(l)` and how does it work. Thankyou.

Comment: @utkarsh13, if you take a look at the original question, they are using lists to store references to the buttons. The `self.buttons` list contains lists for each row of buttons. I'm not assuming why they are being used, only that I needed to preserve the original intent of the question.